# Graphic interface doesn't start (GDM)

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, xorg, gdm

It started after I updated my BIOS settings (virtualization and fast boot). I think I returned them back in place, although I might have changed something and forgot. But my system can't boot normally now for some reason and I don't know what's wrong and what should I check to fix it.

I only see GDM loading bar and then blinking of blank screen with occasional terminal on the startup. I managed to switch to another terminal before but it seems that now I can't even do that -- the login prompt is replaced with black screen again after 2 seconds.

I had a lot of pain setting up the system already, mainly because of the new nvidia card. But now I'm not sure what to check for.

The Secure Boot option is disabled, so that is not the problem.

Comment: Most likely you enabled Secure Boot in UEFI (you don't have BIOS) and that is preventing the Nvidia driver to load.

Comment: @MichaelBay no, it's not it, I remembered that it was a problem when I was setting up. But it switched it again now and the nothing changed. It's called secure option in my UEFI (AMI UEFI), though and it has system and setup options, and I am nottexactly sire what they mean, but neither did work

Comment: Secure Boot now prevents loading *any* unsigned driver. Better disable it.

Comment: @MichaelBay there is no disable option. Only system or startup. And it worked just this morning

Comment: Secure Boot can be enabled/disabled in any UEFI. And it didn't prevent unsigned drivers to load until and from a certain kernel version that may or may not have been installed as an update meanwhile. Nothing else to add, solution has been given but if you insist you know better, I wonder, why bother asking?

Comment: @MichaelBay really, I have tried what I think you suggested, I explained why I am not sure if this was really it and I still didn't see it working, which is why I doubt that it is a good solution, but maybe somebody could suggest what I did wrong. I just find the sentiment of your last response weird

Comment: How did you installed the Nvidia drivers? If from a binary downloaded from the Nvidia website those need to be reinstalled for each new kernel. You wouldn't need to do that if you installed the version already available in the Ubuntu repositories or PPA.

Comment: @MichaelBay it's installed from repository

Comment: If you can't figure out how to disable Secure Boot on your system, you might [edit] your post to include at the very least the make and model. That way someone with the same system or mad skills reading and comprehending manuals might be able to help. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I figured it out in the end, it was disabled. The option was only showing if the OS option in UEFI was set to Windows and is disabled with other OS. Thank you for trying to help, sorry if the question is poorly written.

Comment: @arkhy So did you get it sorted out? Did you install with Secure Boot enabled and then try to rectify the situation by disabling it after the fact? Adding requested details to your question would improve it substantially. Thank you for helping us help you!